# installing selenium ide in iceseasel 3.5.16

Tags: selenium, installation, debian

Could you please tell me how to install selenium ide in iceseasel 3.5.16 (firefox 3.5.16 for debian)?
When I try, iceseasel says:
"Selenium IDE 1.1.0 could not be installed because it is not compatible with Iceweasel 3.5.16."
I only found one version of selenium [there](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) but i can't find one on the [firefox store](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=selenium&cat=all&x=0&y=0)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you considered running Firefox proper? 3.5.16 is pretty outdated, and installing FF on debian (outside apt) isn't hard.

Comment: I installed firefox 5 and it works perfectly! thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Install [plugin](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/2.5.0/selenium-ide-2.5.0.xpi) and click on selenium ide button